# Rewrite Url www.domain.com/model.php?mode=add to www.domain.com/model/add

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

i want to change www.domain.com/model.php?mode=add to www.domain.com/model/add
and not just for model.php but for others as well

previously I've tried like this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/ $1.php?mode=$2 [L]
```

Comment: The first thing I can see, is that if the file / directory doesn't exist, the first rewrite rule will always happen, so you'd end up with "model/add.php" which isn't likely to work. Even if you get beyond that, the second rule expects a trailing /, which isn't in your example URL, so that wouldn't match.

Comment: then how do I get a url like that with filename.php?mode=add

Answer (score 0):

I would be more specific:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ $1.php?mode=$2 [NC]
```

with  NC|nocase to be matched in a case-insensitive manner.

Comment: visible is Internal Server Error